# How to extend a page in Command Prompt?

Tags: cmd, tree, treeview, command-prompt, display

How do I extend a page in command prompt? My issue is when I use the "tree" command there is so many directories that it takes up multiple pages and therefore, cuts off the information at the top.

Comment: This is all set in *Properties - Layout* tab

Answer (score 0):

use

```
tree | more
```

this will make it per page view